# How to normalize OpenCV Android matrices?

Tags: android, opencv, opencv3.0

**tl;dr** My KNearest training data and real data don't have the same dimensions and cause my app to crash. I suspect that either my `preProces` method of the way I instantiate my training data (drawable resource => bitmap => opencv matrix) is the reason for failure. Does any of you know a solution?

I've been trying to get a working demo of a simple OCR app with OpenCV for Android. I use the build in KNearest to recognize the characters. Before a KNearest object is capable of detecting anything, it has to be trained. For the training I use several character outlines.

[image: A black background with the outline of a 0] This is one of them (its a zero).

The training seems to work unsurprisingly it is capable to detect the supposed values of the training images. I wish it did that with other images as well (or at leas not crash my app). This is what I did to train the KNearest model:

```
Map<Character, Integer> images = new HashMap<>();
images.put('0', R.drawable.training0);

// Prepare two sets of data, the images and their values.
Mat trainingImages = new Mat();
Mat trainingLabels = new Mat();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : images.entrySet()) {
        Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            this.getResources(), entry.getValue());
        Mat matImage = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmapImage, matImage);

        trainingLabels.push_back(new MatOfInt(entry.getKey() - '0'));
        trainingImages.push_back(
            preProces(
                matImage, new Rect(0, 0, matImage.width(), matImage.height())));
        }
    }

mKNearest.train(trainingImages, Ml.ROW_SAMPLE, trainingLabels);
```

The `preProces` method does nothing more than normalizing a matrix. This is what my `preProces` method looks like:

```
 private Mat preProces(Mat image, Rect poi) {
    Mat cutout = new Mat(image, poi);
    Mat resized = new Mat(10, 10, CvType.CV_32F);
    Mat converted = new Mat();
    Imgproc.resize(cutout, resized, resized.size());
    resized.reshape(1, 1).convertTo(converted, CvType.CV_32F);
    return converted;
}
```

Segmenting the image to find (possible) characters was not that difficult, I was able to draw rectangles around the (possible) characters. Once that is done I just pass every point of interest through my `preProces` method before I pass it into the `mKNearest.findNeareset(...)` method. This is when the crash happens. The training data and the real data don't seem to have the same dimensions, something the `preProces` method should solve.

My guess is that either my `preProces` method fails or that loading drawable resources as bitmap and then converting them to matrices is the reason why it fails. I'd like to know if some of you had similar problems and how you've solved it.

**Update:** It seems there is quite a bit of noise in the matrices which where created out of a bitmap. Could this be the problem, if so how does one remove the noise?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer to this question was pretty simple. I used `Imgproc.canny()` to detect the edges of the real data but not on the training data. The problem was solved once I passed the training data through `Imgproc.canny()`.

```
...
Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    this.getResources(), entry.getValue());
Mat matImage = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmapImage, matImage);

// This was all I had to add to the training data preparation.
Mat cannyImage = new Mat();
Imgproc.Canny(matImage, cannyImage, 1.0, 255.0);

trainingLabels.push_back(new MatOfInt(entry.getKey() - '0'));
trainingImages.push_back(
    preProces(
        cannyImage, new Rect(0, 0, cannyImage.width(), cannyImage.height())));
}
...
```